# PHP: No such file or directory

Tags: php, tinymce

This is an error that I'm finding difficult to debug because

1. I don't experience it on my local development platform, only on remote servers (but not all) and
2. I'm not sure where to start looking or what PHP settings to investigate although I suspect the issue is to do with the remote server environment.

An additional complication is that, in the large multi-modular script I've developed, the problem only ever occurs in connection with implementation of tinyMCE.  A typical problem is:

> Warning: include_once(core/startup/GLOBALS.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/wikindx/www/www/wikindx4/core/tiny_mce/plugins/wikindxLink/dialog.php on line 33

So in addition to a possible solution to be found in the server environment settings, I might need to change something in the tinyMCE settings -- I've asked several times for help on the tinyMCE forums, but have received no responses.

This all works fine on my local platform and on other remove servers. Needless to say, `GLOBALS.php` is in core/startup/ but I cannot hard-code it to be found in `/home/wikindx/www/www/wikindx4/core/startup/` instead because these scripts must work on any server.

EDIT: I really suspect it has something to do with the tinyMCE environment because the server installation causing the problem has no problem whatsoever calling include_once(`core/startup/GLOBALS.php`) when that call is outside the tinyMCE system. Something in tinyMCE changes the path that `include_once()` looks for.

Comment: Most likely, you are developing on Windows, and the server is *nix? In that case, you should keep in mind filenames are case-insensitive on Windows, but NOT on linux: capital/lower case matters. If that's not the case, inspect what your [`include_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)  is. I usually prefer to include files based on the dir they're in, so that would make it `require __DIR__.'/../../../startup/GLOBALS.php';`

Comment: Developing on OsX. And I can't use your hard-coded path solution for reasons stated above.

Comment: I fail to see why that relative include does not work. Or are you saying you `include` a file _not_ part of your actual package, so the relative to path to the related globals file does not work? (in other words: dialog.php is not part of the same package as GLOBALS.php, but for some reason still knows about its existence and wants to include it from _'somewhere'_?)

Comment: I fail to see why it does not work too. They are part of the same package, core/tiny_mce/plugins/wikindxLink/dialog.php calls core/startup/GLOBALS.php where core/ is the same directory for both paths.  It works fine on my OsX local development system but not on at least 2 remote hosts.

Comment: You misunderstand me. Why is using `require __DIR__.'/../../../startup/GLOBALS.php';` not an option in `dialog.php`?

Comment: Managed to get it fixed with not quite your solution but something similar that was inspired by your suggestion. I still think there's something strange being set in the tinyMCE environment. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'core/startup/GLOBALS.php';
```

On your current server that will have the value `/home/wikindx/www/www/wikindx4/`

Comment: Trying that on my local system (which previously worked), I now get:  include_once(): Failed opening '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/core/startup/GLOBALS.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wikindx4/trunk.

Comment: Again, as the script has to be usable in all sorts of situations and installation paths, I can't hard-code the missing path information.

Comment: Note that `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is _pretty_ reliable, but not for apache vhosts with a `VirtualDocumentRoot` directive.

Comment: You could always build you own function to get the absolute path. YOu could do that based on the $_SERVER and pwd() values or something :) Assign that value to a constant once and you can use it anywhere